# Angular Material 2 Autocomplete with Angular 5

Tags: mongodb, angular, autocomplete, angular-material

i'm struggeling by adding an autocomplete select field to my Site. I'd like to have an autocomplete selectfield filled up with values from my mongoDB. For retreiving these values i'm using my function:

**component.ts**

```
this.availableFirmware = [];

this.terminalService.getFirmware().subscribe(firmware => {
  this.availableFirmware = firmware.firmware;
```

**component.html**

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel2" [(ngModel)]="firmware" name="firmware">
    <option *ngFor="let firmware of availableFirmware" [value]="firmware._id">
        {{firmware.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

this works so far but i need the field to be an autocomplete selectfield which searches for everything. So if my array would be like:

```
[
 'John Doe',
 'Christian Bale'
 'Jenny Doehler'
]
```

i want the function to return `John Doe` **and** `Jenny Doehler` when i'm typing `oe`.

What i did so far was including angular material 2 from http://material.angular.io. I found the example over there [enter link description here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values) but that also does not solve it because i get some errors with the pipe etc. pp. I'm not able to create a simple autocomplete select-field with data which is pulled from my MongoDB.

Hopefully someone can help me!

---

So as further information: This part of code ->

```
this.availableFirmware = [];

    this.terminalService.getFirmware().subscribe(firmware => {
      this.availableFirmware = firmware.firmware;
      console.log(this.availableFirmware);
    });
```

produces this output: [image] and i want to display the name inside my autocomplete field. Thats also the reason why my filter function is not working, because this.availableFirmware is an object and i'm confused on how to split anything in the parts i need for my autocomplete.

Comment: Show us what you have tried using Angular material autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Adding a Custom Filter](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#adding-a-custom-filter) example of the page you referenced.

Open the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qrgodekqnvx?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts) example, the code there looks almost what you want, except the index test should be `> -1` instead of `=== 0`.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(val => this.filter(val))
    );
}

filter(val: string): string[] {
  return this.options.filter(option =>
    option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
}
```

(Unfortunately the StackBlitz provided doesn't work on line, but you can export it if you want to play with it locally).

### Your code

As for integrating the example with your code, add in the `async` pipe because filteredOptions is an observable pipe, not a static array.

I'm assuming the list of options is fetched from MongoDB ***only*** once upon init, so your code will be as below.

I don't think `select` is easily adapted to autocomplete, so if you're ok with angular material, stick with the template in the Angular Material StackBlitz example.

**template**

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput
      [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
      [(ngModel)]="selectedName">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let firmware of filteredOptions | async" [value]="firmware.name">
        {{ firmware.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**component**

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  availableFirmware = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;
  selectedFirmware = null;
  selectedName = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.terminalService.getFirmware().subscribe(firmware => {
      this.availableFirmware = firmware.firmware;
    }
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(val => this.filter(val))
      );
  }

  filter(val: any): any[] {
    return this.availableFirmware.filter(firmware => {
      return firmware.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: my problem is, that `firmware` is an object

Comment: Yeah, there's probably too many things called firmware kicking around in there. Dealing with an object should be trivial, I think you were referencing **firmware.name** at one point, so I guess that property needs to be added into the filter method and the option display. If that's no good, please be more explicit as to why.

Comment: i edited my question and hope that it helps you to understand, where my problem is.

Comment: Ok, I think my previous idea still holds true. Let me adjust the answer, and I'll run a test on the StackBlitz code I downloaded on 24 Dec.

Comment: I've changed the example above to use `firmware.name`, also changed string types to any, and set the model of the input control to a new string property. This all works on my testbed, and I hope I copied all the changes to the answer - if not I'm sure you can see the pattern.

Comment: Note, there's no code there that uses the result after selection, but essentially you need to filter `availableFirmware` by `selectedName` when your'e done selecting. Makes sense?

Comment: Richard... thank you so much! It's working like a charme now - the bounty is gone... is there any possibility to give you those 50 Points? 

I have only one question left, when it's easy to achive... my firmware no. are all like 03.02.01.15 or 03.02.01.25 - so the first part is the same everytime... is it possible to filter for any input so when the user types 25 only 03.02.01.25 is shown?

Many thanks Richard, realy: Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I filter my list:

In the html:

```
(input)="filterfirmware($event.target.value)
```

In the component:

```
private filterItems: any[] = [];
constructor(){}

private(_name: any){
  this.filterItems = []
  this.filterItems = this.availableFirmware.filter((firmware: any) =>
       firmware.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(_name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}
```

`this.filterItems` will have both names now.